# For/In loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-in-loop

My values of delivInfo elements are undefined. The ids match the html file but I am getting a blank output. Kinda lost.

Edit: https://plnkr.co/edit/tTQVvr8MxBsAkzhHxRlz?p=catalogue 
for html code

```html
"use strict"; // interpret document contents in JavaScript strict mode

var delivInfo = {};
var foodInfo = {};
var delivSummary = document.getElementById("deliverTo");
var foodSummary = document.getElementById("order");

function processDeliveryInfo() {
 var prop;
 delivInfo.name = document.getElementById("nameinput").value;
 delivInfo.addr = document.getElementById("addrinput").value;
 delivInfo.city = document.getElementById("cityinput").value;
 delivInfo.email = document.getElementById("emailinput").value;
 delivInfo.phone = document.getElementById("phoneinput").value;
 
 

 
 for (prop in delivInfo) {
  delivSummary.innerHTML += "<p>" + delivInfo[prop] + "<p>";
 }
}

function previewOrder() {
 processDeliveryInfo();
 document.getElementById("previewblock").style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: could you post your code with html in https://plnkr.co/ and update the question

Comment: Post your HTML code also

Comment: I tried to replicate, http://jsbin.com/hucaxoboti/edit?html,js,output, the JS Is fine, check your html. Also, where are you calling the function?

Comment: Where is your `#previewblock` in HTML code?

Comment: editted with html code. previewblock is located in a <section> with id="previewblock"

Answer (score 0):

Call previewOrder after the document is completed loaded.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  previewOrder();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can Try This**

```js
var delivInfo = {};
var foodInfo = {};
var delivSummary = document.getElementById("deliverTo");
var foodSummary = document.getElementById("order");

function processDeliveryInfo() {
  delivInfo.name  = document.getElementById("nameinput").value;
  delivInfo.addr  = document.getElementById("addrinput").value;
  delivInfo.city  = document.getElementById("cityinput").value;
  delivInfo.email = document.getElementById("emailinput").value;
  delivInfo.phone = document.getElementById("phoneinput").value;

  var html = '';

  html+='<p>Name : '+delivInfo.name+'</p>';
  html+='<p>Address : '+delivInfo.addr+'</p>';
  html+='<p>City : '+delivInfo.city+'</p>';
  html+='<p>Email : '+delivInfo.email+'</p>';
  html+='<p>Phone : '+delivInfo.phone+'</p>';
 
  delivSummary.innerHTML = html;
}
```

```html
<p id="deliverTo"></p>
<p id="order"></p>

<input id="nameinput"  placeholder="Customer Name"/>
<input id="addrinput"  placeholder="Customer Address"/>
<input id="cityinput"  placeholder="Customer City"/>
<input id="emailinput" placeholder="Customer Email"/>
<input id="phoneinput" placeholder="Customer Phone"/>

<button onclick="processDeliveryInfo()">Show</button>
```

> **Note :** You defined `delivInfo = {}` as an Object. You didn't defined Array of Objects. So, No need to use `Loops` fot this situation.